# Several instances of pulseaudio on MSI GS65 running Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, msi

After a recent update I noticed I was getting crackling noises and poor audio quality from my headphones and laptop speakers on MSI GS65 running Ubuntu 18.04. Previously, I had to do some tinkering with `hdajackretask` to get the headphone jack to work after installing Ubuntu on this machine. This new issue, however, has removed any saved setting in `hdajackretask`, especially 'Set model=auto' or any override settings I had saved.

After a bit Googling, I found I have a similar issue of several instances of pulseaudio running (the similar issues offered no solution).

Plugging

```
ps x | grep pulseaudio
```

in the terminal gives me:

```
1822 ?        S<l    0:00 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog
4111 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep pulseaudio
```

I am thinking this has to do with Intel audio drivers or potentially a permission issue, but I am unsure what to do next. Side note (unsure if important): the NVIDIA drivers work with no issue and the HDMI port does not detect external monitors which I think is another Intel drivers issue.